# How to get names in alphabetic order in Yii

Tags: yii

In my Yii web application, having student table for saving student details. I want to student name in alphabetical order when retrieve data from student table.

```
 public function defaultScope() {
    return array("order" => "student_firstname");
}
```

I tried this function, but not working properly.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should have worked, as long as you are not overriding it with another scope of your own that's modifying your intended default order by statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `defaultOrder` property of `CSort.` For example...

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Example', array(
  'sort'=>array(
    'defaultOrder'=>array(
      'student_firstname'=>false
    )
  )
));
```

Comment: It's showing no error. But not changing the order of names in alphabetic order.

Comment: Try to change `false` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

In model's search method for data provider try to set default order, like this:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
  'sort'=>array(
    'defaultOrder'=> 'student_firstname ASC'
  )
));
```

Comment: It is working, I used this too many times. Can you update your question with more code so that we can figure out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In model's search method for data provider try to set default order, like this:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                        'criteria'=>$criteria,
                        'pagination'=>array(
                                'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize'],
                        ),
                        'sort'=>array(
                                'defaultOrder'=>array(
                                        'student_firstname'=>CSort::SORT_ASC
                                ),
                        ),
        ));
```